# Get HTML Child Element in HTML String

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, string

I am getting a JSON Reponse from an api in AngularJS.
I have description in it .Description contains HTML Tags in string.
I want to share Response item here.

```
{
  name:'Name of Item',
  Description:'<div>Details: Here is Details</div><div>Type: Here is Type</div>'
}
```

I just want to separate details and Type from description into two different strings.
any body can help.
I tried to search some help, but did not get any 
+ive or match result for this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the HTML string by inserting it into a dummy HTMLElement. Then you can access the text of the nodes by accessing the `textContent` of the `childNodes`.

```js
var data = {
  name: 'Name of Item',
  Description: '<div>Details: Here is Details</div><div>Type: Here is Type</div>'
};

//Create a dummy element to hold the HTML
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = data.Description;

//Get child nodes; can use getElementById, querySelectorAll, etc.
var details = el.childNodes[0].textContent;
var type = el.childNodes[1].textContent;

console.log(details);
console.log(type);
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you need to do some string manupulation. Just like below.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    var data = {
        name: 'Name of Item',
        Description: '<div>Details: Here is Details</div><div>Type: Here is Type</div>'
    }

    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.result = $scope.data.Description.split('</div>');
    $scope.result = $scope.result[0].slice(0, -1); //take the first value from array, and slice last char, which is comma
    $scope.result = $scope.result + '</div>' //insert div at the end
})
```

Comment: I implemented this, but this is not a professional way, BTW I like it :) @Rakesh Burbure

Answer (score 0):

> first extract the description part from json.

Let's say your json is stored in

```
    var response = API call();
    response.data.Description.split('</div>')
```